# Efficient way of killing enemies

Tags: java, android

I currently have this system implemented where when a minion dies I set the minion's x location to -100, thereby moving him out of the screen. But as I add more minions I realise that this will slow down my android game. Is there a better way to remove this minion entirely from the game?

Explanation of the code below. Each minion is created at a specific time interval then added to a arraylist called minionarray. From there each minion in the minionarray is checked to see if the boolean isDead is true for that particular minion. If it is true the miniondeath Animation is started and when it ends the minion is set to -100 thereby removing him from the screen. Need a better way to remove this minion completely from the game.

P.S - Solved. Gil Moshayef's method worked best! Thanks to everyone!

```
for (Minions m : minionarray) {
    m.update();
    if (m.isDead() == true) {

        m.setMinionSpriteCurrent(minDeath.getImage());
        m.setSpeedX(0);
        if (minDeath.getImage() == minDeath4) {
            m.setCenterX(-100);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove the dead minions fron the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove it from the array.

It's a bit of a problem removing items from an array which is being iterated in a "for each" way, but if you change it to a normal for loop, you can do it like this:

```
Minion m;
for (int i = 0; i < minionArray.size(); i++) { // I'm assuming minionArray is a List type
    m = minionArray.get(i);
    m.update();
    if (m.isDead() == true) {

        minionArray.remove(i);
        i--; // set the pointer back by 1 so you don't skip updating the next minion in the list.
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work of course... but for some reason it just feels wrong to modify the index of a for-loop.  Rather use a while loop and keep it clean.

Comment: if you don't like this method, you could accumilate all the minions you need to remove in another array, then remove them after the iteration is finished, but this method will probably have a better run time. changing the index of a for loop is fine, but if it makes you more comfortable, you could do the same in a while loop as well

Comment: What about using foreach, like OP? You don't need index to remove Objects from List. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)

Comment: if this solution worked for you, then feel free to mark it as correct. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend instead of moving them, set them to null so the garbage collector gets rid of them. This way they aren't taking up any memory and aren't using any processing power. (The way your current loops work, unless when they're moved dead is set to false, they will keep being moved back to -100)

Comment: Hmm tried that but I get an error. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply remove the minion from the `minionarray` list. I assume you're iterating over the list to draw and update the sprites; you won't have to apply those operations to minions when you delete them from the list.

```
if (m.isDead()) 
{
      minonarray.remove(m);
}
```

Comment: will cause an error with current method of iteration

Comment: This gave an error for some reason. Appreciate the help though :)